# Powershell 7 suddenly unable to use connect-AzureAD

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell, powershell-7.3

I have a new issue with Powershell7 that I've not encountered before. I've googled around but not seen the exact same issue.

PS version is 7.3.6

I can import module (import-module AzureAD)
but when I try to connect I get the following error instantly & no pop-up appears to sign-in and use MFA:

> Connect-AzureAD: This module does not support PowerShell Core edition. Retry the operation with PowerShell Desktop edition (Windows PowerShell).

More details on my configuration:

PS C:\Users\Banksy> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Is there a way to change the PSEdition from Core to Desktop or is this not the issue? I can use and connect to other 365 resources using modules like; MicrosoftTeams.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is it Linux or MAC?

Comment: Sorry the OS is Windows 11

Comment: Command does not work with all cmdlets.  It says "only with Azure Active Directory cmdlets.  See : "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0#description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error ***"Connect-AzureAD: This module does not support PowerShell Core edition. Retry the operation with PowerShell Desktop edition (Windows PowerShell)"*** usually occurs as Azure AD module is not supported in PowerShell Core.

Refer this **[blog](https://www.varonis.com/blog/connect-to-office-365-powershell)** by *@jeff-brown*, it states that the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module is not supported by PowerShell Core or versions 7 and higher.

Hence as a workaround, **you can try using Windows PowerShell** instead of PowerShell core like below:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Import-Module -Name AzureAD

Connect-AzureAD
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, try installing **`AzureADPreview`** module:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

[image]

**References:**

[Connect-AzureAD not working with Powershell core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674717/connect-azuread-not-working-with-powershell-core) by Rahul Mahajan

[Connect-AzureAD not working with Powershell 7.1.0-preview.1](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12234#issuecomment-608414409) by Aleksandar Nikolić

Comment: Thanks Rukmini. 
I used Powershell5 as you suggested and it worked fine. Reading the links you sent it looks like I need to get Powershell Graph set-up and configured to use that going forward but temporarily used Powershell to get past my urgent issue.

Comment: we can also import a v5 only module into v7 using -UseWindowsPowershell. this will allow us to stay in v7 while being able to run modules built for v5